# Problems displaying several BLOB images from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have this PHP code supposed to show some BLOB images from a MySQL database:

```
<?php
    while ($articulo = mysql_fetch_array($resultados)) 
    {
        ?>
        <div class="categoria">
                <a href="catalogo.php?categoria_serial=<?php echo $articulo['categoria_serial'];?>">
                    <img src="imagenCategoria.php?categoria_serial=<?php echo $articulo['categoria_serial'];?>&ancho=280" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="descripcion">
                <p><?php echo $articulo['categoria_nombre'];?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

The problem is, not every image is shown in the page. Some of the images randomly don't load. If I refresh the page, some of the missing images appear, but some of the correct images dissapear.

Here's the code for every image:

```
<?php
    include 'controller/_init.php'; 
    $db = conectar();
    $desired_width = $_GET["ancho"];;
    $categoria_serial = $_GET["categoria_serial"];
    $resultados = mysql_query("SELECT categoria_imagen FROM categoria WHERE categoria_serial = $categoria_serial") or die("Error");
    $articulo=mysql_fetch_array($resultados);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($articulo['categoria_imagen']);
    $x = imagesx($im);
    $y = imagesy($im);
    $desired_height = $desired_width*$y/$x;
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
    imagecopyresampled($new, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width,$desired_height, $x, $y);
    imagedestroy($im);
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($new, null, 85);
    exit;
?>
```

Any clue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a memory problem - allocating memory for creating each image on refresh... that is a totally bad practice.

You may try saving the images somewhere or at least caching them, so that you don't have to use all the procedure of creating image on each refresh.

Comment: That's right. Saving blob images is a very bad practice that must be avoided.